# How to add custom action to ModelAdmin in Silverstripe?

Tags: php, silverstripe

I have an extension of ModelAdmin called MembershipAdmin.

```
class MembershipAdmin extends ModelAdmin {

  private static $url_segment = 'membership';

  private static $url_handlers = array(
      '$ModelClass/$Action' => 'handleAction',
      '$ModelClass/$Action/$ID' => 'handleAction'
)
```

I want it to recognise the following action and have the action accessible via a URL like this: http://www.example.com/admin/membership/Member/ActivateMember/666 - which is only access in the CMS.

```
public function ActivateMember() {

    $Params = $this->getURLParams();
    $id = Convert::raw2sql($Params['ID']);
    $Member = Member::get_by_id('Member', $id);
    //activate member.
```

However when I run this $ID is not recognised as an URL parameter.

What is the correct way to have ActivateMember run via an URL which is only accessible in the CMS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the first URL handler is matched, not the second one. This means that `$ID` isn't matched.

This happens as handlers don't need to match the entire URL and are checked in order. To correct this, simply have the more specific handler (the one with `$ID`) first in the list.

Comment: Great - thank you. I'm sure I copied that order from an existing verified module, so not sure what's going on there.